# A JNI error has occurred- Docker Oracle NoSQL container

Tags: java, docker, java-native-interface, oracle-nosql

I have been doing research for a couple days and this is my last bullet, hope you guys can help me.

I'm basically trying to make an external table in a Oracle 12c relational database that points to a table of my Oracle NoSQL database. I'm doing so by following [this tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/nosql/external-tables/cookbook.html). Everything went well until reaching point 4, where you generate a ".dat" file by using some libraries. I have my own case with my own data, but you can see a full example of the process [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/bigdata/articles/nosql-db-access-fr-oracle-db-1937066.pdf).

The problem I'm facing comes when executing the following command:

> java -cp ./lib/kvstore-ee.jar:./lib/ojdbc6.jar oracle.kv.exttab.Publish -config ./exttab/nueva.xml -publish -verbose

which leads me to the following error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/kv/KVStoreException

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.kv.KVStoreException
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 7 more
```

Now I proceed with the things I have tried to follow in order to solve this:

- Different JDK versions
- Different versions of the .jar files involved.
- Switching the files to a parent directory
- Executing the command from different directories.
- Checking the code in the classes involved by hand to see if it differed from the original provided by Oracle

At this point, I don't know if it is me that is doing something wrong or there is something wrong with the environment perse. I just need to be able to execute this to generate the ".dat" file but I can't find a way. I leave some information down here in case it helps:

**The environment**. [I am using a Docker container with an Oracle NoSQL distribution](https://hub.docker.com/r/oracle/nosql). In this environment I have installed this jdk version:

- java version "1.8.0_73" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_73-b02) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

I have all the jar files necessary in the paths mentioned in the command, and of course the XML file too. I can also provide you environment variables, code for the configuration file or basically anything you need, but I am lost at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Per the stack trace; the problem is that it can't find the `oracle.kv.KVStoreException` class. I guess that would be in the `kvstore-ee.jar`. You could verify that the class exists in that jar (or elsewhere).

Comment: Hey! I could find the answer thanks to your idea. You can read it if you're interested but in short, it was matter of adding another .jar with these functionalities in the command. It seems that the kvstore-ee.jar doesn't include all the utilities needed, at least, in the version I have.

Answer (score 0):

Ispired in the commet [Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee) suggested, I checked once again in the libraries to see where the class was, as I was sure I had seen it somewhere.

There is **another library** called kvstore.jar with the utilities for the database. As you see, the command didn't make use of this library, where `oracle.kv.KVStoreException` is.

In short, the solution is simply to add this jar to the command, resulting in:

```
java -cp ./lib/kvstore-ee.jar:./lib/kvstore.jar:./lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar oracle.kv.exttab.Publish -config ./exttab/nueva.xml -publish -verbose
```

Then the command executes fine. Thank you for your idea!